# Crear un array en C# con una consulta MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql

necesito crear un array con C# similiar a lo que logré con php.

Este es el código PHP que tengo y con el que logré lo que quería.

```
$consulta = "SELECT unidad_de_medida, itemcode as 'codigo' , qty as 'cantidad', itemname as 'descripcion',  retailsprice as 'valor_unitario', (retailsprice + IGV) as 'precio_unitario', discount as descuento ,    total as 'subtotal', igv ,  ROUND((total + igv) ,2) as 'total', taxapply as 'tipo_de_igv'   FROM sales_item where sales_id='$salesid'";

$query = mysqli_query($enlace, $consulta);

    for ($set = array (); $row = $query->fetch_assoc(); $set[] = $row);
```

Ahora en C# ¿Como lo lograría? Estoy empezando recien, espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

En c# no usas solo un array, deberias crear una clase que mapee con esos campos como ser

```
public class Sale
{
   public string unidad_de_medida {get;set;}
   public string codigo {get;set;}
   public int cantidad {get;set;}
   public string descripcion {get;set;}

   //resto propiedades
}
```

Entonces consultas la db `mysql` y cras una lista de esa clase

```
public List<Sale> obtenerSales(int saleId)
{
    List<Sale> lista = new List<Sale>();

    string consulta = "SELECT unidad_de_medida, itemcode as 'codigo' , qty as 'cantidad', itemname as 'descripcion',  
                        ....
                        FROM sales_item 
                        where sales_id= @salesId";

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta, this.cn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salesId", saleId);

    var reader = cmd.ExecureReader();

    while(reader.Read())
    {
        Sale sale = new Sale();
        sale.unidad_de_medida  = reader["unidad_de_medida"].ToString();
        sale.codigo = reader["codigo"].ToString();
        sale.cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(reader["cantidad"]);
        sale.descripcion = reader["descripcion"].ToString();

        //otras propiedades

        lista.Add(sale);
    }

    return lista;
}
```

Por supuesto completa los campos faltantes, pero basicamente asi es como trabajas en c# cuando consultas datos y nada de array sueltos